# Could HDFS orphan files in datanode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

During a routine log pruning job where logs older than 60 days were being removed, a system administrator upgraded CDH from 4.3 to 4.6, (I know, I know)...

Normally, the log pruning job frees about 40% of HDFS's available storage. However, during the upgrade, datanodes went down, were rebooted, and all sorts of madness.

What's known is that HDFS received the delete commands, since the HDFS files / folders no longer exist, but disk utilization is still unchanged.

My question is, could HDFS have removed the files from the NameNode's metadata without actually fulfilling the file block deletes among the DataNodes, effectively orphaning the file blocks?

Answer (score 0):

I think the namenode tells the datanodes to delete orphaned blocks, once it gets their report on the blocks they hold and it notices that some of them don't belong to any file.

If you don't want these blocks to be deleted, you can put the system in safemode and try to manually look through the disks and copy the data. There is no automated way of doing this, but a tool to list orphaned blocks may be added in the future (as suggested in this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-4015)).

Additionally, you can try to check the health of the namesystem using Hadoop's [fsck](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.7/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#fsck).